# LINQ query error on Inner Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my ASP.NET Core app, I'm getting the following error on the following query:

**Error CS0119**:   'products' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

NOTE: The above error is on the line `join prod in products on.....` of the following query

**LINQ Query**:

```
using System.Linq;
    var innerJoinQuery =
        from category in categories
        join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.ID
        select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name };
```

**category**:

```
public class category
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string categoryNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**product**:

```
public class product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string productNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**NOTE**: This is a `code first` application that has the above model classes among others.

Comment: Since the error says `products`, you probably need to show us the declaration of that, and how it differs from the `categories` declaration.

Comment: @Meligy Thank you for trying to help. I've added product and category classes in my post along with a NOTE at the end.

Comment: This is not about `Product`, it's about `products`, the query says ` in categories` and ` in products`. each of these should be an IQueryable. something like a `DbSet<>`, defined in context (like `dbContext.Products` maybe), or another LINQ query.

Comment: @Meligy Yes, the `categories` and `products` are the DbSet<category> and DbSet<product> names, respectively, in the `ProjNameDbContext` class. So, how my query should look like?

Comment: You should be declared: yourContext db=new yourContext(); then use db.categories or db.products in your query.

Comment: @HaHoang Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Please see my comments below the answer. I'm using the technique used in the controller class [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-a-controller) in official ASP.NET tutorial for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var db = new ProjNameDbContext();
var innerJoinQuery =
    from category in db.categories
    join prod in db.products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID
    select new { ProductName = prod.Name, Category = category.Name };
```

Comment: Your solution works - thank you. I'm using ASP.NET Core, so my controller has class level variable `_context` that in the constructor is set to ProjNameDbContext type. But from your solution I got the idea (I replaced db with _context).